# Prove: Whereas $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that it maybe trivial, but I am trying to understand the full proof using the definition of a open/close set and open/closed ball

So we need to show that for all $x\in (0,1)$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset (0,1)$

by intuition it seems that if we take $\delta=\min\left(\frac{||x||}{2},\frac{||x-1||}{2}\right)$ each ball will be in $(0,1)$ but how do I show it formally?

Comment: Can you write $(0,1)$ as an open ball in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @user251257 because we are in $\mathbb{R}$ it is an interval so I need to find a interval so no matter which point in (0,1) we take, the distance will not "get out" of (0,1)

Comment: $(0,1)$ is an open ball... so it is open by definition.

Comment: $B(0.5,0.5)=(0,1)$, so by definition, $(0,1)$ is open.